# Can't loop through array in vue single file component

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a vue.js app made with single file components. I have an empty array declared in my data:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    teamKeys: []
  }
},
```

Then I push values into it in one of my methods:

```
fetchTeams (token) {
  var this_ = this
  var url = 'myapiserver.com/teams'
  this.axios.get(url, {
    params: {
      accessToken: token
    }
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      var teams = response.data.teams[0].teams
      teams.forEach(function (t) {
        this_.teamKeys.push(String(t.team_key))
      })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
},
```

(updated with actual fetchTeams method)
Then, in another method, I try to loop through it using forEach.

```
fetchRosters (token) {
  var teamKeys = this.teamKeys
  teamKeys.forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(key)
    // do stuff
  })
}
```

The methods are called one after the other in mounted:

```
mounted () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      var accessToken = this.$route.query.accessToken
      this.fetchTeams(accessToken)
      this.fetchRosters(accessToken)
    })
  }
```

The `forEach` loop doesn't work for some reason, it seems like the array is being treated as empty because the inside of the `forEach` never gets accessed. Also, if I do this just before calling `forEach`:

```
console.log(this.teamKeys)
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.teamKeys))
```

the second output is blank `[]`, and the first one is output in console like so:

```
Array(2)
0: "371.l.215756.t.1"
1: "371.l.621475.t.2"
length: 2
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(2), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid. Am I not creating the array properly? Do I even know what an array is?

Comment: why you JSON.stringifying array?

Comment: I don't know, I was trying to diagnose the problem. I guess you can't do that?

Comment: What is `console.log(this.teamKeys.length)`

Comment: hmm, its 0 for some reason. Which makes no sense, because if I do `console.log(this.teamKeys)` just before, it shows up with `length: 2` in the console.

Comment: @greenerr where are you calling `console.log(this.teamKeys.length) `?

Comment: in the `fetchRosters` method, immediately before `teamKeys.forEach`

Comment: Variable `t.team_key` doesnt exist. Use `token.team_key`.

Comment: it does exist, it comes from an axios call, I just didn't include it here (confusing I know)

Comment: Now it is clear whats is wrong...

Comment: your running an asyn task thats why it doesnt get the teamKeys when required

Comment: @zabusa ok, that makes sense. I'm really bad at knowing which tasks are async versus synchronous. Do you have any experience with vue? Any ideas how to rearrange this to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fetchTeams (token) {
  var this_ = this
  var url = 'myapiserver.com/teams'
  this.axios.get(url, {
    params: {
      accessToken: token
    }
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      var teams = response.data.teams[0].teams
      teams.forEach(function (t) {
        this_.teamKeys.push(String(t.team_key))
      })
      //this will run it
      this_.fetchRosters(token)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed '`)`' at the end of the 3rd snippet

Comment: You're right, thanks (fixed), but it's correct in my actual code

Answer (score 0):

```
fetchTeams (token) {
  var this_ = this
  var url = 'myapiserver.com/teams'
  return this.axios.get(url, {
    params: {
      accessToken: token
    }
  })
}

mounted () {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    var accessToken = this.$route.query.accessToken
    this
      .fetchTeams(accessToken)
      .then(function (response) {
        var teams = response.data.teams[0].teams
        teams.forEach(function (t) {
          this_.teamKeys.push(String(t.team_key))
        })
        this.fetchRosters(accessToken)    
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  })
}
```

Or:

```
fetchTeams (url, token) {
  return this.axios.get(url, {
    params: {
      accessToken: token
    }
  })
}

mounted () {
  this.$nextTick(async _ => {
    var accessToken = this.$route.query.accessToken
    var response = await this.fetchTeams('myapiserver.com/teams', accessToken)
    var teams = response.data.teams[0].teams
    teams.forEach(t => {
      this.teamKeys.push(String(t.team_key))
    })
    this.fetchRosters(accessToken)
  })
}
```

Comment: Yea, that looks like a mistake, but the t.team_key actually comes from an axios call. I left that part of the code out in order to simplify here. It's probably not clear in my question.

Comment: updated. I didn't think that part of the code was relevant, as it seems the array is getting data, so I assume the `push` is working. I can see the data in there in my vue developer tools.

Comment: yea, those both make sense. I've got something working as per zabusa's answer, but might try these as well.